# DateTime InvariantCulture with TimeZone

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I'm using DateTime on computers with different cultures. Thus I save the DateTime with `ToString(CutureInfo.InvariantCulture)` which can be read easily on all other cultures. The Format is something like `'01/19/2012 21:00:00'`.

But I want to Add the TimeZone info as well. Yes, I could specifiy the format like

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss+zzz".
```

But my first thaught was, is it possible to Combine the InvariantCulture somehow with the TimeZone?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See following : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by "combining InvariantCulture somehow with the TimeZone"? If you have a fixed format in mind, ToString with a format string will do the job; or am I missing something ?

Comment: Well, just don't and save DateTime.UtcNow instead so you completely don't care.

Comment: The problem ist, that I get the time as local time as well as UTC (in case I store them by myself). I have to distinguish somehow if I have stored them or it comes from customer (as local time in InvariantCulture). My attempt was to store my own with TimeZone (time is still UTC). Thus I can recognize them and convert them from local time. But for storing  I need UTC as InvariantCulture together with TimeZone.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- A time zone and a time zone offset are two different things.  You are asking about offsets.  See [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more on this.
- Since you care about time zone offset, you should use the `DateTimeOffset` type instead of the `DateTime` type.
- Using the invariant culture is good, but you should also be using a format that is unambiguous, because `1/4/2016` could just as easily be either January 4th or April 1st.  The invariant culture will always treat that as January 4th because it is more closely aligned with the United States.  But if someone else reads that string outside the US in some other culture, they could easily confuse it.
- The format you probably want to use is the [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) Extended Format, with offset.  This is nearly identical to the format described in [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339), and also in [the W3C's DateTime note](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). In C#, you can use the `"o"` format to easily get this.

  ```
    DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying. Yes, I meant time zone offset. And I also discovered the new DateTimeOffset class and it seems it works fine for my needs, but not sure, if it covers all my problems.

The two problems I have are
- parsing the date from a string which is saved in invariant culture, but assumed as local and without time zone offset. In the future I will write this with time zone offset, so this problem will disappear
- the date is also saved in SQLite and it does not support time zone offset, thus the offset is gone after reading. I ill check if the database model can be Extended to save the time zone offset also or storing Dates in string format.

In the DateTimeOffset class, what I do not understand is, the Date property is the old DateTime class what permits it to use this property to set the time to midnight for a given date. This needs to change my code in a lot places.